# How do I determine the size of an array?

Tags: c++

So I'm trying to have the user enter strings that will be put into an array with the maximum size of 50 strings. Whenever the user enters "stop", I want the loop to stop and the array to cutoff there.

I then want to read the array back to the user. I tried running this and got a really weird error. Can someone explain to me why this doesn't work and how I would fix it? Thanks.

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]){

    string array[50];

    // Get's inputs for array
    for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++){
        cout << "Enter string: ";
        getline(cin, array[i]);

        if(array[i]== "stop"){
            array[i] = "\0";
            break;
        }

     }

    // Reads inputs from array
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(array); i++){
        cout << array[i] << "\n";
    }

    return 0;


}
```

I don't know why I'm getting down voted so hard?

Comment: Does it have to be an array? This type of thing is much better suited to vectors

Comment: @Leon Oh ok. I haven't gotten to vectors yet in my book

Comment: If your book covers arrays before vectors, it is highly suspect. Every modern C++ book does it the other way around.

Comment: @fredoverflow its the dummies guide to c++ book

Comment: @Suds2 Don't be a dummy, change your book. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) is a list that you can choose from.

Answer (score 3):

Use `std::vector` for your task. It has the method `push_back()` where you can add elements dynamically. Also you can check the size of the vector easily by calling `vector.size()`.

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]){

    vector<std::string> array;

    // Get's inputs for array
    for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++){
        cout << "Enter string: ";
        string line;
        std::getline(cin, line);
        array.push_back(line);

        if(array[i]== "stop"){
            array[i] = "\0";
            break;
        }

     }

    // Reads inputs from array
    for(int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++){
        cout << array[i] << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

In your code you would have to implement a counter that counts, how many inputs the user did.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would use vectors, but since you have not reached that section of the book, I guess they want you to solve it with C-style arrays.

You can get the length of a C-style array like this

```
int size = (sizeof(array)/sizeof(*array)
```

But since you know the maximum number of entries are 50 and that you must stop when you reach the word stop, maybe you rather want this

```
for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++){
    if (array[i] == '\0')
        break;
    cout << array[i] << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I just implemented a loop to find out how long the array is.

```
// Determines how long the array is
    for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++){

        if(array[i] == "\0"){
            break;
        }

        counter++;
    }
```

Comment: in the first loop, before breaking you can set the counter.  counter = i ; right ?